# Azure ServiceBusSender i.c.w. ServiceBusClient possibility to get an event when consumer connects (subscription) to Topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

In my situation we have an Container App which sends messages to a ServiceBus Topic Queue.
Other Apps (also running on Azure) can Subscribe to this Topic and will receive a message when the sender sends a message to the Topic.... this all works fine.

I want also send a message when a "new Consumer" subscribes to the Topic by receiving in the sending application an event (that some new application has subscribed)
Or is there an other mechanism which does the job?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using auto forward feature and filter condition in service bus you can send message when a new consumer subscribes the topic.

- If there are any filter conditions exists for the old consumers, you can use default filter for new consumers in service bus subscription. This will help if your existing consumers have some set of defined filters.
- Create a new subscription in the same namespace and use default sql filter.
- In this scenario, the new consumer will be subscribed because there were no filter conditions specified on that particular consumer.
  [image]
- Once created new subscription with default filter, you can set up forward messages to queue or topic. This option is not available in case of basic tier of service bus.
- Setting up auto forward message can be done while creating queue/ topic or can be edited once created also.
  [image]
- If it is disabled by default, you can click on disabled and configure forwarding message to queue or topic.
  [image]
- In this way you can forward message to queue or topic when a new consumer subscribe topic. As per filter conditions on existing consumers you can filter out new consumer by adding rule on subscription and send message using auto forward feature.

Comment: This option is only available with queue's and not toptic's
It also looks like that it add unneeded complexity to a simple request.
Looks to me that it's a missing event from the client site when a Topic is subscribed unsubscribed etc...

Comment: As mentioned, and attached screen shots, it does not apply only for queues. It will apply for topics also. To check whether a new consumer subscribes topic, the option available with in service bus is adding filter on subscription.